# How can I check if a child view controller exists

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am implementing a slide in style menu.

The menu is added as a child view controller on show, then animated into view. I then remove it from the view once it has been closed.

I would like to introduce a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` so the user can swipe it into view, however the logic for adding the view is only triggered when pressing open.

I'd like to avoid adding it many times and on every gesture, so I was thinking of checking if it was present, if not add it, then animate.

lazy var menuController = MenuController()

```
private var menuWidth: CGFloat = 300
private let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupNavigationItems()
    setupTableView()

    menuController.view.frame = CGRect(x: -menuWidth, y: 0, width: menuWidth, height: view.frame.height)

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

}

@objc func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {


    let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translation.x, y: 0)
    menuController.view.transform = transform
    navigationController?.view.transform = transform

}

@objc func handleOpen() {
    keyWindow?.addSubview(menuController.view)
    animateMenuController(transform: CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.menuWidth, y: 0)) { }

    addChild(menuController)

}

@objc func handleHide() {
    animateMenuController(transform: .identity) { [weak self] in
        self?.menuController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self?.menuController.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

I was hoping to do something like this

```
    @objc func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        if view.subviews.contains(MenuController) {
            print("yes")
        }


        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translation.x, y: 0)
        menuController.view.transform = transform
        navigationController?.view.transform = transform

    }
```

But this is not correct.

Comment: use controller's children property `self.children.contains(MenuController)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the `classForCoder` against your class name

```
if children.first(where: { String(describing: $0.classForCoder) == "MenuController" }) != nil {
    print("we have one")
}
```

This does introduce a "magic string" however as simply changing your class name would break this logic.

Comment: I appreciate your answer

Comment: nodediggity sorry didn't notice that you also where adding an answer ( voted )

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use `childrens` property of the vc

```
if !children.isEmpty { // this assumes 1 vc tell if you have more
   print("YES")  
}
```

or

```
if let _ = children.first(where:{ $0 is menuController})  {  // this assumes 1 vc tell if you have more
   print("YES")  
}
```

you may need also to add it to

```
 view.addSubview(menuController.view)
```

not to `keyWindow`

Comment: assume this scenario, if I add more than one ChildVC in main your condition will satisfy ..?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik then the handling will be different with `count` instead of `isEmpty`  , the edit should have a consequences if necessary

Comment: ya I agree isEmpty is mandatory, but how will know it contains menuController is added or not

Comment: clearly know what do you mean , but the above code is using the vc that the op needs , then any other assumptions should be handled appropriately

Comment: I like you solution @Sh_Khan, based on what OP has advised this should work, if the requirements are more complex, OP should update their post to reflect this